# Make Love2D load resource from inside the .love file

Tags: filesystem, love2d

I've just made my first (very simple, ugly) game in Love2D.  The game works fine when run directly off my hard drive.  However, when I package it up as a `.love` file, I get the following message:

> Error: Could not open file resources/stormclouds.bmp. Does not exist.
>   stack traceback:
>     [C]: ?
>     [C]: in function 'newImage'
>     [string "main.lua"]:46: in function 'load'
>     [string "boot.lua"]:304: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:302>
>     [C]: in function 'xpcall'

The "resources" folder does exist within my directory structure (resources/stormclouds.bmp), and the game runs fine when its not packaged up.

The line of code responsible for this is:

```
bg = love.graphics.newImage("resources/stormclouds.bmp")
```

How can I make this line work for my packaged file?

Comment: You say that "resources" folder doesn't exist, but you still refer to it in code? What does the zip contents look like? There should be a resources directory in the zip and the .bmp file in the folder.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this was what the problem was.  I had used the command given on the Love2d website to zip up my folder(`zip ../${PWD##*/}.love *`), but this doesn't seem to include sub folder contents.  Zipping using a different method did solve this problem.

Comment: I'll formulate that into an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .love files are actually renamed .zip files. These zip files contain directory structures, so if your code refers to, say, "foo/bar.dat", your zip file has to have a "foo" directory with the "bar.dat" contained within.

See http://love2d.org/wiki/Game_Distribution for details.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of this.  The problem is that I ran `zip ../${PWD##*/}.love *` instead of `zip -r ../${PWD##*/}.love *`, which didn't recurse into sub folders.

Comment: The form of the answer was more for the next person who's looking for the answer, and ends up on this page. =)